# Was Zoidberg a competent doctor before the Yeti crushed his skull?

Tags: futurama

In "The Tip of the Zoidberg" we see a fairly well adjusted Zoidberg get his head crushed by the Yeti. Was the Yeti injury the cause of his incompetence?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I edited your question a little to help format it. :)

Answer (score 13):

As The Professor says in *[The Tip of the Zoidberg](https://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:The_Tip_of_the_Zoidberg)*

> ***"Zoidberg's a fine physician. For Aliens. Your mistake is being Humans!"***

Answer (score 12):

I don't think Zoidberg is incompetent.  Zoidberg is actually a competent physician, but not for humans. He is competent in the anatomy of aliens, and even Mom recognizes his skillfulness with aliens. In "The Tip of the Zoidberg", Mom sends Zoidberg to help kill a Tritonian yeti for her bio-weapon.  And it was also Zoidberg that figured out that the Professor had yetiism and not hypermalaria, and knew how to cure him.

Comment: And apparently, being an alien doctor doesn't pay very well :).

Comment: Not true he didn't cure him he just made him a double Yeti.

Comment: @LordApricot Meh. You say tomato, i say tomato...

Comment: *"Mom recognizes his skillfulness with aliens"*  She says 'best' *".. In the **budget category**"*  ;)